# How do I detect whether an iOS/Android app was brought from the background in PubNub?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, pubnub

If an app is in the background, and the user receives the push, and the user taps on the notification, thus making the app active, how do I detect in PubNub whether the app was brought from the background as in this case? Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Android & iOS have delegates/events that handle this and at that point, you could manually do whatever is necessary. However, PubNub's SDKs reconnect and retrieve missed messages automatically. [Android requires some extra code](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/190/how-do-i-resume-an-android-connection) but pretty trivial. There are is some level of customization that you can do when you initialize PubNub in the app.

See the [Android SDK docs](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-java-sdk) and [iOS SDK docs](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4) for more details and contact support@pubnub.com, if needed.